# Release Management - creative naming ideas?

Tags: release, naming, release-management

Currently brainstorming release names for an application.  Theme is mythological creatures.  What are some themes/names that you have used or would like to use?

1.0 is Kraken "Release the Kraken!"

Chimera, Centaur, Chpacabra, Wargon, Manbearpig, Minotaur, etc.

Comment: This belongs on programmers.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a project where new releases followed mountain ranges or peak names per version in alphabetical order.  For example:  project Alpine was the first release.

I also think it would be neat to follow major project releases in order of the presidents of the United States.  Version Washington, Adams, Jefferson, Madison, Monroe, Adams, Jackson, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go in alphabetical order. If you really want Kraken first that's fine, but next do an L, then an M, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler.  Within a theme, it may be difficult. Is Apple bucking best-practices by takes the liberty? Leopard, Snow Leopard, Lion etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've always favored the Norse Cosmology for a good pool of interesting names. There are many Gods, Giants, and Creatures to choose from.